# Decoupling type traits definition from implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Lets consider the following class which checks if the type provided is a string and uses type traits to call a different function based on the result. The original source has type dependencies on Obj, this is a simplified example:

```
template <typename Obj> 
class example {
    public:            
        template <bool IdIsString = std::is_same<std::string, Obj>::value>
        typename std::enable_if<IdIsString, void>::type
        doStuff() {
            this->object->doSomething();
        }

        template <bool IdIsString = std::is_same<std::string, Obj>::value>
        typename std::enable_if<!IdIsString, void>::type
        doStuff()  {
            this->object->doSomethingElse();
        }
     private:
        AnyObject object;
};
```

How would I go about decoupling the definition (e.g. storing it in a example_inline.hpp) from the class without providing each type trait case in the definition?

An ideal solution would look like this:

```
// header.hpp
template <typename Obj> 
class example {
    public:
        void doStuff(); 
}

// header_inline.hpp
template <typename Obj>
template <bool IdIsString = std::is_same<std::string, Obj>::value>
typename std::enable_if<IdIsString, void>::type
example::doStuff() {
   // ...
}

// ...
```

The above is obviously not possible. One solution would be to decouple the type_trait function from the class and put it into a detail namespace but this would mean that I would have to always pass AnyObject (and in that sense, all objects that are modified by the function) to it which seems not very elegant.

Is there a good solution for this problem? I'd really like for the headers in question be easily readable without cluttering them with tons of enable_if's.

Thanks for any input on the matter.

Comment: What about tag dispatch?

Comment: @dyp Didn't know about that idiom, but it seems to be an ideal solution :) I'll mark your answer as accept in case you want to elaborate on it for other people having the same problem.

Comment: What about a simple `if`? In your example, there seems to be no dependence on the actual type, so both calls are valid and you could just use an `if(std::is_same<std::string, Obj>::value)`..

Comment: There are quite a few type dependencies in the original source, I just left it out of the function bodies. Tag dispatch is ideal for the code I'm working with, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload based on the return value of `std::is_same`:

```
template<typename T>
class example
{
private:
    void doStuff(std::true_type)
    {
        obj->doSomething();
    }

    void doStuff(std::false_type)
    {
        obj->doSomethingElse();
    }
public:
    void doStuff()
    {
        doStuff(std::is_same<T, std::string>{});
    }
};
```

Comment: Which is also called tag dispatch :) But I failed to formulate my answer as a haiku :(

Answer (score 2):

In this simple case, you could also specialize `doStuff` on the template parameter of the class template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
struct example
{ void doStuff(); };

template<class T>
void example<T>::doStuff()
{ std::cout<<"default\n"; }

template<>
void example<std::string>::doStuff()
{ std::cout<<"string\n"; }

int main()
{
    example<int>{}.doStuff();
    example<std::string>{}.doStuff();
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/049b6c16096fe064)